# Connecting to Windows Network Share Drive from NodeJS inside Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, fs

Been banging my head with this, and would appreciate any help! I did search, and found a few potential solutions, but all were a no go for me.

I have a nodejs application developed in windows, and is now running in a docker container (using the node:latest image). The application needs to connect to a shared windows network drive to perform read/writes, but it doesn't seem to be working when the application runs inside the docker container (It works fine when it is run on my windows machine outside of docker).

The network drive shared folder looks something like this. Shared to everyone:

\\myserver\test

The Nodejs code (not quite but gives you an idea of how I am accessing file):

```
let fileLocation = "\\myserver\test\file.pdf"
let readStream = fs.createReadStream(fileLocation)

// When the stream is done being read, end the response
readStream.on('close', () =>
{
    // End response
    response.status('200').end()

    // Remove the file
    fs.unlinkSync(fileLocation)
})

// Stream chunks to response
readStream.pipe(response)
```

This works fine when run in nodejs on windows, but I keep getting a "ENOENT: no such file or directory" error when run inside the nodejs docker container. I'm not sure if this is a linux OS (which the node image is based on) or a docker permission/priviledge issue. The file does exist.

This is the command I'm using to test when I'm running the container

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 myapplication:latest
```

New to docker, but Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mounting the volume using `docker run -v` (see [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v-read-only)).

I'm hoping it will work on your Windows network share drive.

**Update**

Syntax of volume mounting in Windows is:
`docker run -v c:/Users:/data alpine`

Where c:/Users is the Windows directory on the host machine you'd like to mount (equivalent to C:\Users in Windows syntax), and data is the name of the mounted directory inside the running container.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding; this is what I ended up doing yesterday,. Mounting the volume and accessing that way. It's an additional step, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please mention the 'docker run -v" full statement that worked for you in here?

Comment: I don't recall exactly, but the syntax on Windows is something like this: `docker run -v c:/Users:/data alpine`

Where `c:/Users` is the Windows directory on the host machine you'd like to mount (equivalent to `C:\Users` in Windows syntax), and `data` is the name of the mounted directory inside the running container.